# cv_bridge segmentation fault OpenCV 3.0

Tags: cv-bridge, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
I have compiled and installed from source OpenCV 3.0 and the project I had now throws a segmentation fault error.
I tracked down the callback that causes it

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg){
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_image;
  cv_image = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);
  (cv_image->image).copyTo(frame_);
}
```

It seems that cv_bridge has a problem with the new version of the library.

For this specific project I can use OpenCV 2.x without any problem, however for other projects (both ROS and non-ROS) I have to use OpenCV 3.0.

How can I solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219305/cv_bridge-segmentation-fault-opencv-3.0/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2015-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this with `cv_bridge` installed from `ros-jade-cv-bridge` and your from-source OpenCV? If so, that is most likely the issue: binary compatibility is only guaranteed when all packages that depend on OpenCV depend on the exact same version.

---

Edit:

> Yes, this is the case. Is there any way I can edit my CMakeList.txt to force link with another OpenCV version?

There is (something like `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)`), but I'm not sure that is what you want.

> I can install the 2.x one along with the 3.0 Do you believe is a good idea?

If you installed any ROS Jade packages that depend on `cv_bridge`, you should already have an OpenCV 2 version installed. The issue is that you are probably linking your executable with `cv_bridge`, which pulls in OpenCV 2 dependencies, but also with OpenCV 3, which won't work.

If I remember correctly, @Vincent Rabaud has been working on OpenCV 3 ROS integration. He might be able to work out the best way to do this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-10-19**:
Yes, this is the case. Is there any way I can edit my CMakeList.txt to force link with another OpenCV version? I can install the 2.x one along with the 3.0
Do you believe is a good idea?

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-10-19**:
I see. What I meant was not to force link to OpenCV 3.0 but to the built in OpenCV of ros

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:\

> Unfortunately downgrading OpenCV is not an option

and

> What I meant was not to force link to OpenCV 3.0 but to the built in OpenCV of ros

This seems conflicting to me: if you can actually use OpenCV2, then there would be no issue, right?

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-10-19**:
No, there would not. I probably explained myself wrong. What I meant was that I could not unistall OpenCV 3.0. At the moment I do not know how to link to the built in version of ros.
The OpenCV 3.0 are needed for another project. Therefore, is fine to me to use the older ones to compile this package

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
Ok, so could you please update your original question with some more details? If I understand you correctly, you have:

1. ROS nodes that *should* just use OpenCV2
2. an installation of OpenCV3 which you *only* need for non-ROS projects?

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-10-19**:
Not exactly. I have:

1. A ROS project with independent ROS workspace that requires (apparently) OpenCV 2
2. Other project bot ROS (that will have their own workspace) and non-ROS

hope this cleared out a bit

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:\

> hope this cleared out a bit

Not really. I'm not sure how a binary `ros-jade-cv-bridge` could be linked at runtime against your from-source OpenCV 3, unless you are also doing `find_package(OpenCV)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, and *that* is pulling in CV3 libs.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-10-19**:
Ok. I am actually doing as you are suggesting, but this implies that the software links to the **new** version of OpenCV. How should I do to link it to the old version?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
To get CMake to find the old version, you can try something like `find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)`, which should find the older version. You'll want to `(build,run)_depend` on `libopencv-dev` (in >= Indigo).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-19**:
The only way to use OpenCV 3 with your other ROS projects would be to build everything in `opencv_vision` from source, making sure it finds your new version, *or* by not using `opencv_vision` at all, being very careful, and just link *your node(s)* with OpenCV 3. But that will likely be brittle.

**Comment by [mariam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26656/mariam/) on 2016-04-21**:
Hi, I have the exact same problem mentioned above and I've tried adding find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED) to my CmakeLists but it doesn't work. How can I (build,run)_depending on libopencv-dev ?